# HTML / PHP Page Load Optimization - Why the Gap in Elements Loading (Pingdom FPT)?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, caching, minify

I have an interesting question about PHP / HTML page speed optimization, and an issue on a certain site that I've not experienced before.

Website is a WordPress site. It is hosted on a medium sized Amazon EC2 instance in Europe (Ireland). There's plenty of RAM and CPU to load the site.

To further optimize, we installed W3 Total Cache (as on nearly every WP site I work with) and have gone for browser caching, page caching, db caching, opcode caching and Amazon CDN - in varying arrays.

There is a gap between the head elements loading and the body elements loading when we do full page test at Pingdom. This APPEARS to begin when minification is turned on. Why the gap in the elements loading? Anything we can do to fix this?

Comment: Note the reason I say "APPEARS" is that, without minification, the gap is not visible, as all the (uncombined) JS and CSS could potentially be obfuscating the time lag. It might be a theme issue, but I'd love to know WHY!?

Comment: Would you show a screen shot of the problem? By gap, I take it you mean a space on screen, and not a time gap? (If you have extra detail to add to your question, please edit it rather than adding addendums to comments).